# Get value of a specific item in a row of Gridview with Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this Gridview :

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridViewSearch" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceSearch" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SURNAME" HeaderText="SURNAME" SortExpression="SURNAME"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FIRSTNAME" HeaderText="FIRSTNAME" SortExpression="FIRSTNAME"></asp:BoundField>               
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True"></asp:CommandField>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">                  
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonPrint" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/images/printSmall.png" CssClass="addbuttons" OnClientClick = "return PrintPanel();" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

In the last column I have the imagebutton "ImageButtonPrint". I wont to run the following Js :

```
      <script type = "text/javascript">
    function PrintPanel() {

        var name = '<%# Eval("SURNAME")+Eval("FIRSTNAME") %>';//this is not working

        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=800,width=400');
        printWindow.document.write(name);
        printWindow.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
            printWindow.print();
        }, 500);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that I can't get the equivalent value of surname + firstname from the row of the dropdownlist

```
   var name = '<%# Eval("SURNAME")+Eval("FIRSTNAME") %>';
```

This is not working.
Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try passing SURNAME and FIRSTNAME in your function like

```
OnClientClick='<%#String.Format(“return PrintPanel(&#39;{0}&#39;,&#39;{1}&#39;)”, Eval(“SURNAME”),  Eval(“FIRSTNAME”)) %>’
```

and change your function definition like

```
function PrintPanel(Surname,Firstname) {

        var name =Surname+' '+Firstname;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

First you will need to pass the control as parameter, so your `OnClientClick`  attribute of your `asp:ImageButton` will be like this

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonPrint" ... OnClientClick = "return PrintPanel(this);" />
```

now receive it in the function and we are going to use the [parentNode property](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) until we get the `<tr>` element and then get the text inside the cells you want like in an array

```
function PrintPanel(element) {

    var name = element.parentNode.parentNode.cells[1].innerHTML + 
         ' ' + element.parentNode.parentNode.cells[2].innerHTML;

    // If you want to verify the var
    // alert(name);

    var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=800,width=400');
    printWindow.document.write(name);
    printWindow.document.close();
    setTimeout(function () {
        printWindow.print();
    }, 500);
    return false;
}
```

I think this code is clearer than the other one